# Cannot animate (0).(1) on an immutable object?

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, combobox, themes

I have a ComboBox with a custom theme I wrote, and I get the error message "Cannot animate (0).(1) on an immutable object." This specifically happens when I set its `selectedindex` after the user selects one of the options in the combobox.

Doing some research online, I found that this is a common issue with databound items or dynamic resources. I'm not using any databound resources, but what I think is happening is since the combobox is collapsed, it tries to set the state of a button that doesn't exist. I narrowed it down to this code:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
  <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
     <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource spPressedStateBrush}" />
  </Trigger>
  <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
     <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource spOverStateBrush}" />
  </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Which depends on these Dynamic Resources:

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="spOverStateBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
    <GradientStop Color="#2C8CBF" Offset="0" />
    <GradientStop Color="#2793BF" Offset="0.5" />
    <GradientStop Color="#2483BF" Offset="0.5001" />
    <GradientStop Color="#2C8CBF" Offset="1" />
</LinearGradientBrush>

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="spPressedStateBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
    <GradientStop Color="#0C6C9F" Offset="0" />
    <GradientStop Color="#07739F" Offset="0.5" />
    <GradientStop Color="#04639F" Offset="0.5001" />
    <GradientStop Color="#0C6C9F" Offset="1" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

So I'm pretty sure those dynamic resources are the culprit, but how would I solve this problem?

Comment: You narrowed the code a bit too much. Show us more please. Upload your project somewhere online. Those are all triggers, where is the animation?

Comment: @devhedgehog oops I said animation by accident, they aren't animated they're instant, I'll update the question

Comment: Can you show full code? I have a trigger works fine setting of a dynamic resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After painstakingly trying to debug it by comparing the code to the [original Control Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), I figured out that transporting all of the resources that my control uses into the file itself, and replacing all `DynamicResources` with `StaticResources` and that fixed the bug I was having.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that both this two (`spOverStateBrush` or `spPressedStateBrush`) Brushes are not used in different place in your code.

In order to be animatable, the Background Brush (`spOverStateBrush` or `spPressedStateBrush`) of the **`Border`** must be mutable, which the default value isn't.

If you use one of these two Brushes in another place, You should assign a new LinearGradientBrush before animating something like this code:

```
    LinearGradientBrush gradient = new LinearGradientBrush();
    gradient.StartPoint = new Point( 0.5, 0 );
    gradient.EndPoint = new Point( 0.5, 1 );

    gradient.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Black, 0));
    gradient.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Color.FromArgb(100,69,87,186), 1));

    Border.Background = gradient;
```